# Is Amy Pond Clara's grandmother?

Tags: doctor-who, amy-pond

Is Clara's gran really Amy Williams, née Pond?

I noticed that they both had the same ring on.

Comment: Please bring more references to make your claim. At the very least, bring pictures of both rings to show they're identical. Personally, I didn't think they were identical at all.

Comment: I do not think so. Their functions (story-line-wise) were very separate. Can you show **any** evidence to support you hypothesis?

Comment: If Amy is Clara's grandmother, then Clara's mother must be River Song, right?

Comment: @MrLister: Amy had other children, so not necessarily.

Comment: Amy was wearing her wedding set, that we'd seen a million times and is a large six-prong vintage basket setting with a gold band. Old gram lady there is wearing a pearl ring.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith so what? One of Amy's adopted kids may have had Clara as a child. So River wouldn't necessarily be Clara's mother.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith if you adopt a child and this child has a daughter, you're still that kid's grandparent... It's irrelevant whether it's a biological link...

Comment: @CarlSixsmith MrLister was just asking if River Song would be Clara's mother, which is obviously not necessarily true because Amy may have given the ring to any of her adopted kids. You don't need to be a biological child to receive a ring... Hence it is irrelevant.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith what does that even matter for MrLister's question? He only wants to know if River could be Clara's mother. Which is not necessarily true because anyone may have received the ring in question. Instead of telling me that "it is important" maybe you should tell me **why** it is important, because as far as I am concerned an adopted kid can have Amy's ring and henceforth that kid may be Clara's mother.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith it does not change the answer. River is not necessarily Clara's mother. For all we care, Amy could have given the ring to some random girl in the street. Your "correction" is absolutely useless and hence **irrelevant**. You are being pedantic with a ridiculous detail that helps nobody at all because the answer is exactly the same: before and after this whole discussion. Biological? Adopted? Same answer.

Comment: We know what year Amy died, so she couldn't be.

Comment: grrr, spoiler in question title!

Answer (score 23):

**No they didn't have the same ring on.**
[image: Difference between the Rings]

SO, no Clara's Granny is not Amy Pond.

There are also various other reasons, like the fact that Amy and Rory's son's last name was Williams, not Oswald OR Ravenwood.

Amy and Rory were dead by 2012, which was proved in THE ANGELS TAKE MANHATTAN when they arrive and the Doctor says they're in 2012. Clara, being 24 and born in 1989, is from 2013, and her grandma is clearly alive and well.

Comment: Plus Amy died in New York, probably around the turn of the Millennium. Clara’s gran is likely having Christmas lunch in 2013.

Comment: And Clara's grandmother did not show any particular familiarity with the Doctor, which she should have if she were really Amy.

Comment: Clara probably had _two_ grandmothers -- nearly everyone does, after all. So the _other_ one could be Amy.

Comment: @MikeScott For the love of God, will *somebody* be Amy?!

Comment: @MikeScott I'm Amy Pondicus!

Comment: @MinaBrennan This question has now been un-protected, so if you want, you can use your edit as a basis for your own answer. It is really too radical a change for an edit, but it would be a good answer in its own right. That way, people could vote on it. O, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

No. Amy said she could not have any more children after Demon's Run.

> AMY: Whatever they did to me at Demons Run, I can't ever give you children.
>
> <sub>-- [*Asylum of the Daleks* (Series 7 Episode 1)](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-1.htm)</sub>

Comment: In theory, she could still have adopted a child who wasn't her biological child. (Welcome to Stack Exchange, by the way! I took the liberty of adding a canonical source to your answer, to improve it and forestall downvoters.)